# Why are /// comment blocks important?

Tags: c#, comments

Someone once said we should prefix all our methods with the  `/// <summary>` comment blocks (C#) but did not explain why.

I started to use them and found they annoyed me quite a bit, so stopped using them except for libraries and static methods. They're bulky and I'm always forgetting to update them.

Is there any good reason to use `/// <summary>` comment blocks in your code?

I normally use `//` comments all the time, it's just the `/// <summary>` blocks I was wondering about.

Comment: I wasn't sure if these comment blocks were personal preference or recommended standards

Comment: I think SO as well.

Comment: I think this is exactly the kind of question that belongs here. There's a good chance that this would be closed on stackoverflow as being subjective.

Comment: Use <summary> blocks if you want to generate documentation. This would make sense if you are making an API for others to use. Doing this for every method is overkill and decreases your flexibility.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

> **Use them as much as possible.**

Yes, those are special comments that become the documentation for the method. The contents of `<summary>`, the parameter tags, etc. that are generated show up in intellisense when you or someone else is getting ready to call your method.  They can essentially see all the documentation for your method or class without having to go to the file itself to figure out what it does (or try to just read the method signature and hope for the best).

Comment: +1 Absolutely use them.  You would be surprised at how useful it is to have them if you ever reuse your components and have all that great documentation available in intellisense.

Comment: Also if you're using Visual Studio and begin a line with /// just before a class, method or field declaration, VS will generate the XML documentation structure for you - you just have to fill it in.
I agree that it takes up a lot of space of your screen, but it's a worthy compromise I'd say. Also, F# has some better support for it (e.g. you don't have to use <summary> and </summary> since they are 'assumed').

Comment: Because this answer is already the best choice I will just add my comment: When I found out that the summary is used for intellisense, and my projects grew to their current size, I was very glad to have found this feature. Remembering what my methods and classes are for was becoming a huge challenge, and documenting code via this mechanism greatly simplified things, allowing me to focus on new code and resusability instead of trying to remember what was done months ago.

Comment: Just one thing to add, these comments *aren't* compiled into the dll, you have to deliver the associated xml file with your dll.

Comment: They are usefull, but they make the current class very unreadable. I wish there was another way which doesn't cluttering the code.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, absolutely use them for anything you want to keep, or might be shared.

Also, use them in conjunction with [Sandcastle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sandcastle/) and the [Sandcastle Help File Builder](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB), which takes the XML output and turns it into beautiful, MSDN-style documentation.

Last place I worked we re-built the documentation every night and hosted it as an internal homepage. The company initials were MF, so it was MFDN ;)

Normally though I just produce a .chm file, which is easily shared around.

You'd be surprised how addicted you get to documenting everything once you start seeing it in MSDN format!

Comment: The link to the blog appears to be dead (last post 5 years ago with broken html all over the page), and the location of the project has moved. Do you have an updated link for Sandcastle?

Answer (score 12):

If your coding standard demands that you use such comments (and a coding standard for an API or a framework may demand that), then you have no choice, you have to use such comments.

Otherwise, consider seriously not using such comments.  You can avoid them in most cases by changing your code like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if a user is authorized to access the resource
    /// </summary>
    public bool SecurityCheck( User user ) {

    }
```

to

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if a user is authorized to access the resource
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsAuthorizedToAccessResource( User user ) {

    }
```

to

```
    public bool IsAuthorizedToAccessResource( User user ) {

    }
```

Comment: While I agree code should be self-documenting as often as possible, I suggest using these types of comments whenever possible (and more often than generic // comments).  The /// XML comments are designed to work with IntelliSense, which can make development easier months down the line when you're trying to implement some library you built and don't quite recall how it works any longer.

Comment: And I think not only from an Intellisense perspective, from an automatic documentation generation perspective as well, xml comments are useful. But as with all comments, this only makes senses if the comments themselves are useful, and are adding to the self documented code.

Comment: I agree that when you're writing public classes of an API or a framework, the coding standard should demand that you put comments in the code such that IntelliSense and documentation tools can plug into.  But that's not all code.  Aside from that concern, the approach I'm advocating here is, when you try to make your code cleaner and clearer, focus on the code itself, not the comment that describes the code.

Comment: I agree some methods can be named more verbosely for clarity of function. But at the same time, I don't want to fill my screen with calls to `CheckIfDataQualityExceedsLevelForSensorThenWriteFileIfTrue(XmlDocument LastDataFromSensor)`

Comment: @JYelton: your comment misrepresents my answer. I implied more descriptive names, but not necessarily much more verbose ones, certainly not a 60-character identifier for a frequently called public function.  Also, you have what seems to be a highly specialized function, but it takes a very general data type (XmlDocument) - that's one code smell.  Then, your 60-character identifier describes "how" and not not "what" - of a public method.  That's another smell.  The main message is: think first about the code, not the comment.

Comment: @JYelton The problem with your method name is not that it is descriptive, but rather it describes at least 2 separate operations and therefore should be refactored into at least 2 independent methods.

Comment: @Neal & azheglov: Drat, I was just trying to invent an overly verbose method name to illustrate a point, and apparently didn't put *enough* thought into it! Both of you are right of course, it's just that I have occasionally ran into some pretty long names and prefer shorter names that are a good compromise between self-explanatory and shorthand.

Answer (score 4):

Your class, method, & property naming should be self evident, so if you need these, it's probably a smell.

However, I would recommend using them on any public classes, methods, & properties in an API, library, etc...   At the very least, they will generate the docs to help any dev using your it, and will prevent you from having to write them.

But anyway you slice it, maintain them or delete them.

Comment: Naming is one thing, but listing constraints on parameters or potentially thrown exceptions is still valuable.

Comment: Yes, I will concede you have a point, but most of the time the parameter constraints are obvious aren't they?

Comment: Not sure I agree with John. With this logic, none of the .net framework methods should get any Intellisense help.

Comment: @vaibhav - I did say "I would recommend using them on any public classes, methods, & properties in an API, library, etc..." ... that would cover what you're talking about doesn't it?

Comment: @John: Not necessarily. Say you have a string parameter. Obviously a non-empty string should be okay... but does it need to be in a particular format? What happens if you do pass in an empty string (or a null)? And so on. As a somewhat related aside, I've also seen a complete aberration -- parameters named in a way that expressed their constraintsm e.g. 'int numNotZero'.

Comment: @Anna Lear - "int numNotZero" ?  .... yuck!  ;-)

Comment: @John MacIntyre: Yep. I still don't know what that parameter is actually supposed to be... other than not zero. :)

Comment: @John - strange, I could have sworn that I read something else altogether when I wrote that comment. Because your second paragraph is exactly what I said elsewhere in this thread. So, I must have rocks in my head for writing that comment. Yes, I agree with that.

Answer (score 2):

Forgetting to do something doesn't make it a bad idea.  Forgetting to update any documentation is.  I've found these very useful in my programming and people that inherit my code are thankful to have them.

It is one of the most visible ways to document your code.

It is a pain to have to find the source code to read inline documentation or dig up a document that goes over what code does.  If you can have something useful pop up through intelligence then people will love you.

Answer (score 2):

If you find that you have to keep going back and editing your comments to correspond with new code, you might be doing them wrong in the first place. The summary element should contain exactly that - a summary - the *what* and the *why* of the thing your'e summarising.

Describing *how* something works in comments violates DRY. If your code is not self-descriptive enough, maybe you should go back and refactor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've created them. [when building new systems from scratch]

No, I've never benefited from them. [when working on existing systems that needed maintenance]

I've found that "Summary" comments eventually tend to get out of sync with code. And once I notice a few badly behaving comments, I tend to lose faith in all comments on that project - you're never sure which ones to trust.

Comment: Stale comments can be considered a code smell though, even more so at the summary level. If other developers are changing functions and not updating the summary of what they are doing then one could argue they aren't documenting their work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> "**It has to be Used Very much, like me ;)**"

I used to play with comments (///). For a class you can simply do a comment like this

```
namespace test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Calendar.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class DatePicker : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
```

But, for a method you can add-on more with giving description for parameters and return types.

```
/// <summary>
/// Assign selected cases to the participating users based on the filters and configurations
/// </summary>
/// <param name="noOfParticipants">No. of participants to the Table</param>
/// <param name="value">Value of the participant</param>
/// <returns>No Of Cases Assigned on successfull completion</returns>
public long AssignCasesToParticipatingUsers(int noOfParticipants,string value)
{
```

You can use a short-cut for creating this comment `(///+Tab)`.

Answer (score 0):

> using them except for libraries

That's the time they are useful. With XML Documentation generation turned on and a reference to the assembly, without its project, will show more detail in intellisense.

But for the internals of the current project, they just get in the way.

Answer (score 0):

I use them, but as some other people have said not universally. For small methods they can easily be larger than the code they're explaining. They are most useful for generating documentation that can be given to people new to the system so that they have something to refer to while learning it. Even though, as programmers, we can usually ferret out what some code is for it is nice to have the comments to guide us and act as a crutch. If it **has** to be written down somewhere then in the code is the place it is most likely to stay updated (more likely than some Word document floating around).

Answer (score 0):

I use the equivalent in VB (since they won't let me use C# - apparently it's too hard... no comment.)  I find them very convenient.  Most of the time I wait until the procedure or function is pretty much completed before putting them in, if only to avoid having to change the comments - or have them "out of sync".

I don't necessarily write a novel - just the basics, the parameter description and some remarks (usually when there's something "out of the ordinary" going on in there - workaround or other crap that I'd rather not have in there but have no choice "for now".) (Yeah, I know, that "for now" can last years.)

I'm severely irritated by uncommented code.  A consultant wrote the initial version of one of our components and didn't comment anything and his choice of names leave to be desired here and there.  He's been gone over a year and we're still sorting out his stuff (in addition to working on our own stuff.)